# Connect VB.NET to Sybase DB using ASE connection

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, database-connection, sybase

I am using Visual Studio 2010.

I have just installed Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise PC Client 15.7.

When I try to use `Imports System.Data.AseClient`, in Visual Studio, it is not recognized.

Consequently when I try to create a new `AseConnection`, I get an error stating that `"Type AseConnection is not defined"`.

I'm sure it's an easy fix, any help is appreciated.

Comment: there are Sybase dlls out there for different versions of .net so make sure the one you choose matches the version in your software

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have a reference to the `AseClient` DLL in your project's `References` folder.

Comment: ah okay, thank you. I don't suppose you know where the correct AseClient.dll is stored?

Comment: `The default location is C:\Sybase\ADO.NET\dll.` per the [Sybase documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sdk_12.5.1.adonet/html/adonet/DAFJEFIF.htm).